# Can I use Geotools in Android Studio?

Tags: geotools, android

I want to use Geotools in Android Studio but get this error:

```
Could not resolve org.geotools
```

This is part of build.gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main" }
    maven { url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/" }
    google()
    jcenter()

  }
}
```

Geotools library

```
implementation group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-api', version: '20.3'
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57945819/how-to-use-geotools-in-android-how-add-geotools-lib-to-android. To my knowledge you still can't use GeoTools as a whole on Android as it has dependencies on a number of Java libraries that Android does not contain. You might be able to use specific subsets of GeoTools, though.